Semaphore locking isn't locking properly
I created two threads thread1 and thread2. thread1 executes the write_ticket function which makes ticketnumber=5000; it then sleeps for a second and then prints it. the accessing of ticketnumber is a critical section, and hence it has been sem locked.
in ticketIncrease it increments the ticket by 1 and prints. as it is accessing the critical section, it is also sem locked.
Here's my code.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int ticketnumber=0;
sem_t sem;

void write_ticket(){
    sem_wait(&sem);
    ticketnumber=5000;
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n",ticketnumber);
    sem_post(&sem);
}

void ticketIncrease(){
    sem_wait(&sem);
    ticketnumber+=1;
    printf("%d\n",ticketnumber);
    sem_post(&sem);
}

int main(){
    sem_init(&sem, 0, 1);
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,(void *)write_ticket,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,(void *)ticketIncrease,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
}

Now ideally I expected it to print 5000 first and then 5001 as thread1 executed the critical section 1st and then thread2. But guess what! I am getting 5001 and 5001 as output.
The above problem doesnt exist if I replace sleep with some print statement.

can't reproduce on ubuntu 22 with gcc 11.4.0. Could you please recheck your exampla?

Have you tried linking with -lpthread?  Some platforms and/or compiler versions  require you to do so explicitly to get correctly functioning threads/semaphores etc.

I get the same result as @IngoLeonhardt -- it prints 5000 then 5001.

Note that 1 5000 is also a valid outcome - there's nothing which forces thread1 to run first.

The thread start functions write_ticket and ticketIncrease have the wrong number of parameters and an incorrect return type, resulting in undefined behavior. Hiding the error with a cast to (void *) doesn't make it OK.

You do not check the return values of any of your function calls to verify that they succeeded.  If any of them are failing then you may indeed not be getting any locking.

To expand on what @G.M. posted, you may also need to define specific feature test macros prior to #include statements, such as _POSIX_C_SOURCE and/or _XOPEN_SOURCE.  For Linux, also see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

@IngoLeonhardt   I ran my program on macos sonoma, with the same gcc version however.

@ShreyankGopal Read this: sem_init on OS X  Your lesson here?  Always check return values.
